# RASA: Intent ranking without normalisation

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I want create model with config for which resultat as like below. I mean the ranking of intentions that do not add up to 100%, but each individual intention takes a value in the range of 0-100%.
I need an example configuration in RASA, for which I will not get a ranking of intentions whose values ​​will add up to 100%.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nn0Z.png)

Comment: Hi, could you provide some more context around the concrete use-case/problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I add more information in here: https://forum.rasa.com/t/intent-ranking-different-measurement/40048/8